# KiCad 5.1: New footprint from existing footprint

Tags: kicad, footprint

Is there a way to duplicate a footprint in one library into another for making changes? Or "create new footprint starting with existing footprint"?

I want to make a footprint for Adafruit's [Itsy Bitsy 32u4](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3675). It's basically a 28 pin 0.6" DIP with five additional pins along one of the short ends. I *could* make it from scratch, but the built-in 28 pin DIP footprint has everything I need (except for the additional five pins, which should be easier to add than creating the footprint from scratch).

Adafruit provides Eagle files for their products, so it may be possible to import one of those into KiCad then extract the PCB as a footprint, but if that's my only option, I'll probably create the footprint I want from scratch as practice.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You need to create a library in some local folder. And then you can select it while saving footprints, after editing new or existing footprints. Also make sure to manage footprint libraries in preferences so the library shows up in all projects (global libraries).

Comment: @Indraneel If you convert this comment to an answer, I'll consider accepting it. Either way, thanks for the quick response!

Comment: You can go ahead and accept Seth's answer. His brief long answer is easy to follow. I myself do not know any simple way to go about it. This is because kicad gives options at every window, same thing can be accomplished in any number of ways. It is a bit confusing unless one is familiar with all the options. So Seth's steps seem simple enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.  @Indraneel's comment is exactly correct.

Long answer with steps:

First create a new library into which you want to save the modified footprint. You do this from the File menu.

[image: Create New Footprint Menu]

Next, choose where you want to save the library and specify what type of library you are creating.  A project library is accessible only from the project you have open.  A global library is accessible from all projects on your computer.  As a general rule, I only create project libraries.  I usually copy the global footprint into my local library when I use it in my projects.

[image: Library Type]

After you have created the new library, it will be listed in the Tree on the left.  Next, you find the footprint you'd like to copy and right-click on it's name.  Then select "Save As"

[image: SaveAs Footprint]

You will then be presented with a list of the footprint libraries.  You select your newly created library and click OK.

Comment: You can also add screenshot of save as window, although your answer is pretty much complete. I too am often confused about where to find what.